# Question marked wrong duplicate

Tags: discussion

The following question has been marked duplicate although the linked question is clearly for Magento 1 while the asked question is specifically for Magento 2.

[How to increase character limit of text field in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264283/how-to-increase-character-limit-of-text-field-in-magento-2)

Comment: Fixed it........

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this question got the proper explanation and fixed the issue

Comment: I think closing the question will remove it from future search result of magento se ...